# Como selecionar todos os elementos de uma mesma id em Javascript em Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Tenho uma tabela em Django onde estão armazenadas todas as respostas de uma prova, mas quando seleciono elas para comparar com a resposta fornecida pelo usuário, todas as respostas ficam iguais a da primeira questão. Sei que isso tem a ver com o getElementsById, que só seleciona o primeiro elemento. Mas como faço para selecionar todos os elementos de mesmo id no HTML?

```
{% for resposta in questao.resposta_set.all %}

  <input type="hidden" id="resposta" name="resposta" value="{{resposta.resposta}}">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarSel() {
      if (getRadioValor('opcao_escolhida') == document.getElementById("resposta").value) {
        alert('Resposta Correta');
      }
      else{
       alert('Resposta Incorreta');
      }
    }
    function getRadioValor(name){
      var rads = document.getElementsByName(name);
      for(var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++){
        if(rads[i].checked){
          return rads[i].value;
        }
      }

      return null;
    }

  </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [`id` deveria ser único no DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Se você possui vários elementos com o mesmo `id`, você fez algo errado.

Comment: Sim, tenho ciência que fiz errado. Agora gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para consertar este erro.

Comment: Certo. O que seriam essas funções JS dentro do `for` e quando elas são chamadas? Com essa informação, acredito que conseguirei responder o que precisa.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Estou comparando um value de uma das options de um select com um um valor que está salvo no Banco

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não está escrito corretamente, você não deve criar um `script` dentro do loop, esse `js` está afetando não só o HTML do laço, mas tudo que foi renderizado na página.

A lógica correta seria separar o HTML do JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
    {% for resposta in questao.resposta_set.all %}
        <div class="questao">
            <input type="hidden" name="resposta" value="{{resposta.resposta}}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**JavaScript (com jQuery)**

```
var questoes = $('.questao');
$.each(questoes, function(num, questao){
    // sua lógica: 
    if (questao.find("name=[resposta]").val() == questao.find("name=[opcao]")){
        alert('opção correta');
    }
});
```

Não sei como está seu código HTML, você colocou apenas um trecho. Nesse caso eu criei um loop usando jQuery que verifica cada questão e dispara um `alert` quando está correta. Você pode customizar isso, ou ainda mandar disparar uma ação quando o usuário selecionar uma opção e o código checar apenas aquela resposta.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Vou colocar aqui meu código para que você possa me ajudar melhor, pois estou perdido. https://pastebin.com/BemsxnVH

Comment: @MurilodeJesus a minha resposta já apresenta a lógica que você deve utilizar para elaborar seu código. O JavaScript deve ficar fora do HTML, cria um `arquivo.js` responsável por validar suas questões, se você não souber usar `jQuery`, recomendo procurar sobre o assunto, ou realizar novas questões de forma específica sobre sua dúvida. Lembrando que aqui ninguém vai fazer o trabalho para você, apenas ajudar em dúvidas e em direcionamento.

Comment: Aliás, minha resposta já responde sua questão que é um problema de estruturação e lógica. Se tiver outra dúvida, elabore uma nova questão de forma específica e encerre essa. Modificar a questão atual pode levar ao fechamento da pergunta.